# Strcpy and strcat functions in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015

I'm using the C programming language in Visual Studio 2015, and I'm simply trying to prompt the user for three sentences of text that are then combined into one, three sentence paragraph. I just can't get my strcpy and strcat functions to work. 
Thoughts??

Thank you so much in advance!

```
#include <string.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MASTERSIZE 300

int main()
{

char *calcTotalMessage(char[100], char[100], char[100]);
#define MSIZE 100
#define MSIZEE 100
#define MSIZEEE 100

int read;
char message[MSIZE];
char m2[MSIZE];
char m3[MSIZE];
char* totalM;

printf("Enter a sentence:");

scanf_s("%s", &message);

printf("Enter another sentence:");
scanf_s("%s", &m2);

printf("Enter third sentence:");
scanf_s("%s", &m3);

totalM = calcTotalMessage(message, m2, m3);
printf(totalM);

return 0;
}

char *calcTotalMessage(char *m1, char *m2, char *m3)
{
void strcat(char, char);
void strcpy(char, char);
char *totalM = "";

strcpy(*totalM, *m1);
strcat(*totalM, *m2);
strcat(*totalM, *m3);

return totalM;

}
```

Comment: What goes wrong and how? Describe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
char *totalM = "";
```

So totalM points at a string literal. Modifying literals is disallowed by the C standard. You won't necessarily get a compile time error, but your program has undefined behavior. It's unlikely to behave properly.

```
strcpy(*totalM, *m1);
```

Then you attempt to pass `strcpy` a char (the type of `*totalM` and `*m1`), and not a pointer. That character is converted to some nonsensical pointer value that you attempt to write at. That again results in undefined behavior. You compiler even tried to warn you, but instead of heeding those errors you added declarations for functions that don't exist (`strcpy(char, char)`).

I suggest you pass the output buffer into `calcTotalMessage` instead of returning it.

```
void calcTotalMessage(char const *m1, char const *m2, char const *m3, char *output) {
    output[0] = '\0';
    strcpy(output, m1);
    strcat(output, m2);
    strcat(output, m3);
}
```

To be called like this:

```
char totalM[MSIZE + MSIZEE + MSIZEEE] = {'\0'};
calcTotalMessage(message, m2, m3, totalM);
```

---

A point regarding style. You won't usually see function declarations anywhere but at file scope. So don't get too used to declaring functions inside another function scope.